# Explore components dependencies inside a React project

Tags: reactjs

Is there some VsCode extension, tool or tip to get some graph or report of the internal dependencies of React components, inside a React project?

Specifically, suppose I have defined my component `<MyComponent .../>`; I wish to know which other components (always inside my project) include it as children, like  `<ParentComponent> ... <MyComponent .../> <ParentCOmponent>` and, viceversa.

Comment: I mean you can do a global proejct search *(Cmd/Ctrl + Shift + F)* and search for  `<MyComponent />` but I don't know of any specifc graphing tool

Answer (score 1):

### 1. GUI

One useful tool for outline the **component tree** -or- Debugging is the `React Developer Tools` chrome extension (Components tab).

**Download here:**
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

**Component tree Screenshot:**
[image]

**Search:**
[image]

Related: https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/08/15/new-react-devtools.html

### 2. By code:

`React.Children`
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren